# TukeyHSD p-value is less than t-test p-value

Tags: r, anova, tukey-hsd-test

I have some data where when I do `t.test` for a specific pair of groups, the p-value is (barely) higher than when I do `TukeyHSD` and include all 6 comparisons.

I was under the impression that the adjusted p-value would always be higher and I'm wondering why it isn't.

This is very small data - only 8-10 measures per group and I am thinking that perhaps the difference is in how each procedure handles groups of different sizes?

Comment: To confirm, you have 4 treatment groups, correct (resulting in 6 possible pairwise comparisons)? Additionally, is it ok to assume your observations are all independent? Next, when performing the t-test are you only using the data from the two groups of interest for that test, or do you have a larger model with a contrast for those two groups?

Comment: The overall ANOVA and Tukey HSD use fundamentally different distribution theory. Both are based on the assumption data are normal. But even if all ANOVA assumptions hold, what you observe _can_ happen---rarely (then usually only 'barely'), but possibly.

Answer (score 4):

For a single data set, this can happen. But the *probability* that the t-test will reject will be higher than that the TukeyHSD-test rejects this comparision.

One of the assumptions is the homogeneity of variance. Let's assume that even though the assumption is fulfilled the sample within-group-variance in your data is (just by chance) very high for these two groups you referenced. The single t-test then overestimates the variance and therefore gives a high p-value, while the TukeyHSD-test uses the pooled sample variance and gives therefore a lower p-value.

For example if generate data in the following way, we would expect the effect you have seen (which would violate the assumptions - but this data could of course also occur by chance under the assumptions):

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(y=c(rnorm(10), 
                       rnorm(10, mean=1),
                       rnorm(50, sd=0.5)),
                   group=rep(LETTERS[1:3], times=c(10,10,50)))

boxplot(y~group, data=dat)
```

[image]

```
 TukeyHSD(aov(y~group, data=dat))
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = y ~ group, data = dat)

$group
          diff        lwr        upr     p adj
B-A  1.2649867  0.5198000  2.0101734 0.0003695
C-A  0.2405365 -0.3366827  0.8177556 0.5801783
C-B -1.0244502 -1.6016694 -0.4472311 0.0001951

t.test(dat$y[dat$group=="A"], dat$y[dat$group=="B"])

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  dat$y[dat$group == "A"] and dat$y[dat$group == "B"]
t = -2.7404, df = 17.914, p-value = 0.01349
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.2351190 -0.2948544
sample estimates:
 mean of x  mean of y 
-0.3831574  0.8818293
```

As you can see the $p$-value of the t-test for comparing group A and B is 0.01349 and higher than the adjusted $p$-value of 0.0003695, since we have a higher sample variance if we only look at these two groups.

Comment: thank you this is very helpful; in such cases which p value should we report? I also saw the same issue with pairwise comparison whereby the resulting p with boneforonni is actually lower than the single t.test.

Comment: You should not report the smallest p-value, but decide beforehand which method you want to use. And how can your Bonferroni corrected p-value be smaller? You multiply your p-value by the number of comparisons (cutting it at 1 if this would result in a number bigger than 1).